# Como usar projeto feito para localhost no Tablet?

Tags: php

Como posso usar um projeto que criei em PHP para ser usado somente em localhost também no meu tablet.

Fazer a conexão entre eles?

Comment: Você quer acessar pelo browser do tablet uma aplicação que está numa máquina qualquer sem acesso externo, isso?

Comment: Qual o seu sistema operativo? Como configurou o seu ambiente, utilizou programas como WAMP, MAMP, etc... ou fez uma instalação de raiz? Tem possibilidade de ligar o tablet na mesma rede que o computador?

Comment: Se vai fazer conexão entre 2 maquinas, já não é mais localhost. Melhor [edit] e deixar mais claro.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes é wampserver o meu sistema vai ser usado apenas no localhost , mas quero conectar meu tablet em localhost , mas obrigado .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver na mesma rede, por exemplo, sua maquina e o tablet conectados no mesmo wifi, basta pelo browser ou o app que você fez (caso seja esse o caso) apontar para o IP da maquina com o PHP, como se fosse o servidor.

Se no seu navegador você digita:
http://localhost/meuapp/pagina-legal.php

No tablet você chama assim:
http://000.000.0.00/meuapp/pagina-legal.php (sendo os 0 seu IP)

Algo como
http://192.168.0.15/meuapp/pagina-legal.php

Comment: Ótimo, só pra complementar, você pode achar o seu IP local usando o comando ipconfig no CMD (caso use Windows), ou ifconfig no terminal (caso use Linux/MAC).

Comment: @NeubeOliveira terei que colocar a porta também pois só assim não funcionou , ou tenho que fazer alguma conexão do tablet com o pc que é o servidor ?

Comment: @allanaraujo depende de como ta configurado seu ambiente, basicamente é so substituir localhost por ip mesmo, ate por que se a aplicacao em php estivesse em uma porta diferente provavelmente voce teria que fazer algo assim:  http://localhost:8080/meuapp/pagina-legal.php por exemplo. O que exatamente de errado?